# less-sbt changes my source files when it compiles

Tags: playframework, less

Real simple.

I am using playframework 2.4.x.

I have a file app/assets/stylesheets/main.less with these contents:

```
@import "lib/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";

// This should not go away!


body {
    background-color: #6600FF;
}
```

When the project recompiles (activator compile, or a file load using ~run) the file is then reverted to one that contains only the import line:

```
@import "lib/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
```

I get no error messages, no obvious complaints, it just seems to silently fail.

What might I be doing wrong?

What setting might I want to check to make sure I didn't mess something up?

My first assumption is user error rather than a bug.  My Google skills have failed me thus far.

Contents of build.sbt:

```
name := """webgame"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.6",        //Bootstrap
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.38"   //Mysql
)

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator


// The following two lines should automatically add any .less files in app/assets/stylesheets
// to the list of assets to compile, as well as telling it to skip any files that have an
// underscore ("_") at the start of their name.  This should let us use an underscore to designate
// a file to treat as a partial.
//
// A partial is a chunk of code that is put into an individual file for use in other files, like
// an include file or similar.  It is part of the DRY approach to writing reusable code.
//
includeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "*.less"
excludeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "_*.less"
```

Contents of project/plugins.sbt:

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.6")

// Web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")

// Play enhancer - this automatically generates getters/setters for public fields
// and rewrites accessors of these fields to use the getters/setters. Remove this
// plugin if you prefer not to have this feature, or disable on a per project
// basis using disablePlugins(PlayEnhancer) in your build.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

Comment: Since this seems like a build issue you might want to provide details of which SBT plugins you're using (in `project/plugins.sbt`) and the contents of your `build.sbt`.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Information added!